# Unable to resolve path with os.walk

Tags: python

I have a bit of code that searches for files in a network share that match a certain keyword. When a match is found, I would like to copy the found files to a different location on the network. The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user.name/PycharmProjects/SearchDirectory/Sub-Search.py", line 15, in <module>
shutil.copy(path+name, dest)
File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 119, in copy
copyfile(src, dst)
File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//server/otheruser$/Document (user).docx'
```

I believe it's because I'm trying to copy the found file without specifying its direct path, since some of the files are found in subfolders. If so, how can I store the direct path to a file when it matches the keyword? Here is the code I have so far:

```
import os
import shutil


dest = '//dbserver/user.name$/Reports/User'
path = '//dbserver/User$/'

keyword = 'report'

print 'Starting'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
  for name in files:
      if keyword in name.lower():
         shutil.copy(path+name, dest)
         print name

print 'Done'
```

PS. The user folder being accessed is hidden, hence the $.

Comment: I have edited the title to make this question more likely to come up in a Google search. I don't think network shares are particularly relevant here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk), your error is most likely that you are not including the full path. To avoid having to worry about things like trailing slashes and OS/specific path separators, you should also consider using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Replace `path+name` with `os.path.join(root, name)`. The `root` element is the path of the subdirectory under `path` actually containing `name`, which you are currently omitting from your full path.

You should also replace `dest` with `os.path.join(dest, os.path.relpath(root, path))` if you wish to preserve the directory structure in the destination. [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) subtracts the path prefix of `path` from `root`, allowing you to create the same relative path under `dest`. If the correct subfolders do not exist, you may want to call [`os.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.mkdir) or better yet [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.makedirs) on them as you go:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
  out = os.path.join(dest, os.path.relpath(root, path))
  #os.makedirs(out) # You may end up with empty folders if you put this line here
  for name in files:
      if keyword in name.lower():
         os.makedirs(out) # This guarantees that only folders with at least one file get created
         shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, name), out)
```

Finally, look into [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree), wich does something very similar to what you want. The only disadvantage is that it does not offer the fine level of control for things like filtering that `os.walk` does (which you are using).